# Getting two strings as input from user, not the button value

Tags: javascript, html, forms, function, io

I have this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form id="frm1" action="form_action.asp">
  First name: <input type="text" name="fname" value="Donald"><br>
  Last name: <input type="text" name="lname" value="Duck"><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<p>Click "Try it" to display the value of each element in the form.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("frm1");
    var text = "";
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < x.length ;i++) {
        if(x.elements[i].value)
            text += x.elements[i].value + "<br>";
    }
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Which will treat "Submit" string from the Submit button as an input string to. Obviously, assuming that the user won't input "Submit", I could hardcode-check if the value is "Submit" and skip it.

Isn't there any other way?

Comment: `object.onsubmit=function(e){};` OR `object.addEventListener('submit',function(e){});` then use the e object to access the form elements. AFAIK `button` is excluded in `e.target`.

Comment: Correct @divyaSharma, but for that baby example, it doesn't really matter, thank you though! :)

Comment: @divyaSharma - *"use the e object to access the form elements"* - The OP's "Submit" button *is* a form element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *I could hardcode-check if the value is "Submit" and skip it.*

Checking the *value* doesn't work because the user might actually type the word "Submit".

You can test the type of the elements:

```
if (x.elements[i].type === "text") { ... }
```

Or you can just select the text elements directly using [the `querySelectorAll()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll):

```js
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.querySelectorAll("#frm1 input[type='text']");
    var text = "";
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < x.length ;i++) {
        text += x[i].value + "<br>";
    }
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
}
```

```html
<form id="frm1" action="form_action.asp">
  First name: <input type="text" name="fname" value="Donald"><br>
  Last name: <input type="text" name="lname" value="Duck"><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<p>Click "Try it" to display the value of each element in the form.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: Right, the selector! Thank you n²*n³! :)

Answer (score 2):

Display just elements with a name:

```
for (i = 0; i < x.length ;i++) {
    if(x.elements[i].value && x.elements[i].name)
        text += x.elements[i].value + "<br>";
}
```

Possibly more useful than only selecting `text` inputs since you don't have to recode if you have other types - plus, reinforces that these are the items that would get sent during form submission.

And because I was bored:

```js
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = 
        Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll("#frm1 input[name]"))
             .reduce( ( prev, curr ) => 
                 { return prev + curr.value + "<br />"; }, "");
}

document.addEventListener( "DOMContentLoaded",
    function() {
        document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click", myFunction, false);
    }, false );
```

```html
<body>
<form id="frm1" action="form_action.asp">
  First name: <input type="text" name="fname" value="Donald"><br>
  Last name: <input type="text" name="lname" value="Duck"><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<p>Click "Try it" to display the value of each element in the form.</p>
<button id="button">Try it</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can check the element's type (`x.elements[i].type === 'text'`):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form id="frm1" action="form_action.asp">
  First name: <input type="text" name="fname" value="Donald"><br>
  Last name: <input type="text" name="lname" value="Duck"><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<p>Click "Try it" to display the value of each element in the form.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("frm1");
    var text = "";
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < x.length ;i++) {
        if(x.elements[i].value && x.elements[i].type === 'text')
            text += x.elements[i].value + "<br>";
    }
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```